# Conexão reiniciada

Tags: php, yii

Abaixo esta o codigo da minha classe main

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Web Application',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    'aliases' => array(
            'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'), 
            'audit' =>  realpath(__DIR__ . '/../modules/audit'),
                  ),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
    'application.controller.*',
    'application.components.*',
        'application.modules.audit.models.*',
        'application.modules.audit.components.*',
        //'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',
        'application.modules.audit.*',
    'application.extensions.bootstrap.*',  
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
     'audi',
         'audit' => array(
         'class' => 'application.modules.audit.AuditModule',
         'userViewUrl' => array('/audit/view', 'id' => '--user_id--'),
         'enableAuditField' => false,
         'connectionID' => 'db',
         'autoCreateTables' => true,
         'layout' => 'application.modules.audit.views.layouts.column1',
         'gridViewWidget' => 'application.extensions.bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',
         'detailViewWidget' => 'zii.widgets.CDetailView',
         'controllerFilters' => array(
         'auditAccess' => array('application.modules.audit.components.AuditAccessFilter'),
                ),

         'adminUsers' => array('admin'),
         'yiiStrapPath' => 'application.vendor.yii-audit-module',
            ),

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'12345',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
            'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
        ),

    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(

         'errorHandler' => array(
            //'class' => 'application.modules.audit.components.AuditErrorHandler',
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
            'trackAllRequests' => true,
           // 'catchFatalErrors' => true,
            'auditRequestIgnoreKeys' => array('PHP_AUTH_PW', 'password'),
                            ),

        'bootstrap' => array(
                    'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi',   
                        ),

        'user'=>array('allowAutoLogin'=>true,),

        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            //'audit'=>'audit/default',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        /*
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),
        */

        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'enableProfiling' => true,
            'enableParamLogging' => true,
        ),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                     'class' => 'application.modules.audit.components.AuditLogRoute',
                     'levels' => 'error, warning, profile, audit',
                      ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
                        ),
                ),
    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

Abaixo o erro especificado

Estou iniciando em Yii e configurando uma extensão, só que está surgindo o seguinte erro:

[image: Mensagem de erro]

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes? Descreva o seu servidor e tudo o que você está usando. Não há como ajudar apenas com a informação que você deu.

Comment: estou usando o servidor xampp, o que eu fiz @GuilhermeBernal configurei a minha classe main de acordo com a especificação do site mas na hora que vou exibir os formularios acaba gerando o erro da imagem

Comment: estou usando o yii framework no php, quero configurar a extensao Yii-audti-module

Comment: Mostre código. Mostre a configuração que usou. Diga o que quer dizer "exibir formulários". Pode fazer tudo isso [editando](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/21164/edit) a pergunta?

Comment: coloquei o codigo da minha classe main

Comment: conseguiu ver o codigo??

Comment: Sim. Mas eu entendo muito pouco do assunto para poder formular uma hipótese/solução. Pedi informações para que outros viessem ajudar, agora é esperar.

Comment: Tranquilo estou aguardando deve ser uma coisa bem simples para se resolver mas nao estou enxergando o erro, preciso resolver logo isso :) muito obrigado

Comment: Bom dia @GuilhermeBernal conseguiu alguma coisa a respeito do codigo?

Comment: Não é minha área, eu não sei nada a respeito de php. Como disse, não sou eu quem vou te ajudar, não sei qual é o problema nem nada que lhe seja útil. Outros virão. Enquanto isso, procure sempre melhorar a pergunta. Quanto melhor escrita e mais informativa estiver, mais provável que alguém apareça.

Comment: ta ok muito obrigado pela atenção

Comment: O problema continua ou já foi resolvido?